# WPF Catch Ctrl + N Not Working

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, kiosk

Hello and thank you for reading.

I have an embedded WebBrowser in a Kiosk style WPF application and I am attempting to prevent the user from being able to use the Ctrl + O or Ctrl + N keyboard shortcuts to circumvent the page that I have limited them to.

Here is my code which is in the top most window of the application:

```
// This is in the constructor of the window under InitializeComponent();
AddHandler(Keyboard.PreviewKeyDownEvent, (System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler)HandleKeyDownEvent);

private void HandleKeyDownEvent(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
   Key key = (e.Key == Key.System) ? e.SystemKey : e.Key;
   if(e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
   {
      switch(key)
      {
         case Key.N:
         case Key.O:
         case Key.P:
            MessageBox.Show("BOOM");
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

The event handler is properly triggering when I press Ctrl + N, but e.Key is Key.Control not Key.N. It appears that the event triggers immediately when the Ctrl button is pressed (as expected), but fails to capture the N key. I have tried using Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.N) and that returns false as well.

Any advice or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Adam

**EDIT: I have also tried to prevent a new window using the NewWindow, NewWindow2 and NewWindow3 events on the browser itself. No luck there either.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel like a complete numb skull! Turns out it is as simple as adding the following line of code. I hope this helps other people that may be trying very overcomplicated solutions like I was.

```
     browser.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
```